# (C# Winforms) When creating a new form in code, why is it rendered with slightly smaller dimensions than assigned?

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

I'm creating a small dialog programatically like this:

```
    public static class EntryList {
    public static List<string> ShowDialog(List<string> entries) {
        Form entryList = new Form() {
            Width = 250,
            Height = 500
        };

        //some code

        entryList.ShowDialog();
    }
    }
```

When you call this method from elsewhere, it should create a form of 250x500. However, it's actually created of dimensions 234x471 (so, -16 in width and -39 in height). I've tried adding those numbers in the parameters, like this:

```
            Width = 266,
            Height = 539
```

And now, this actually generates the 250x500 form I want. I don't like hardcoding fixes for problems like this, though, so I wonder if there is something I'm missing that is reducing my form dimensions.

Comment: Did you consider the fact that a form has borders and a caption? The dimension you give are the external size for the form, while the client area (the surface where you host your controls) has a lesser area

Comment: You can directly set the Form's ClientSize to the measure you prefer. The overall Form size will adjust.

Comment: Does your designer.cs file contain a line of code `this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13)` ? Does the problem go away if you remove it?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot with your on screen ruler indicating what it is you're actually  measuring?

Comment: [Here is a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/TjlkrW6.png) The current dimensions in my code are 266 and 404 (changed Height a bit since I wrote this post), which are exactly 16 and 39 pixels bigger than what is displayed in the screenshot. The dimensions do not count purple borders and header, only the grey area (the form proper).

I haven't found this.AutoScaleBaseSize in the designer file, only AutoScaleDimensions and AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font. The second one does not change anything when changing it to None, the first one goes wild if I touch it.

Comment: The *gray area* is the Client Area. If you want a Client Area of a specific dimension, then set the `ClientSize` property to that specific measure. I also suggest to set `AutoSizeMode = Dpi`. Then comes DpiAwareness. But that's a longer story.

Comment: Thank you! It solved it. I'd read about DpiAwareness.